# Kendo UI Uploader: Angular directive doesn't post files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am working with Angular and Kendo together, and I'm trying to implement the upload widget using the angular-kendo directives written by Kendo Labs.

I have a controller, called "EditWorkspace".  In that controller I defined the kendo-upload directive's options as

```
 $scope.uploadOptions
```

The callback functions for the uploader are defined inside the controller.  From the documentation, I was led to believe that this is what the directive expects.  These options are used across multiple elements.  I don't seem to have a problem until I actually try to post the files to a server, at which point ALL arrays are empty ($_POST, $_FILES, $_GET, $_REQUEST, etc) which I know because I dumped all the arrays out to see what was in them.

I've tried switching all configuration to my own directive in which I invoke

```
$(element).kendoUpload()
```

But I get the same result.  Files get inside the form just fine and send a message off to the server, but they post empty arrays.

Has anybody had a similar experience with either Kendo or Angular and can you shed some light on it?  I could post all kinds of code but I don't think it would help to explain.